# Javascript Date constructor can't parse date string with some timezones without brackets

Tags: javascript, parsing, date

Consider following examples

```
new Date("Wed, 28 May 2014 09:50:06 EEST"); // Invalid Date
new Date("Thu, 26 Jun 2014 09:09:27 EDT"); // OK, is parsed
new Date("Wed, 28 May 2014 09:50:06 (EEST)"); // OK, is parsed
new Date("Thu, 26 Jun 2014 09:09:27 (EDT)"); // OK, is parsed
```

Why "EEST" example without brackets is not parsed whereas second example is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EEST` is not a valid time zone *at all* in this case. The parenthesized versions are simply being ignored, regardless of contents.

For example (I'm in the Eastern zone):

```
// Eastern, by default
new Date("Thu, 26 Jun 2014 09:09:27");
Thu Jun 26 2014 09:09:27 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

// Eastern, explicitly
new Date("Thu, 26 Jun 2014 09:09:27 EDT");
Thu Jun 26 2014 09:09:27 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

// Central, explicitly
new Date("Thu, 26 Jun 2014 09:09:27 CDT");
Thu Jun 26 2014 10:09:27 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

// Ignored, so eastern
new Date("Thu, 26 Jun 2014 09:09:27 (CDT)");
Thu Jun 26 2014 09:09:27 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

new Date("Thu, 26 Jun 2014 09:09:27 (EEST)");
Thu Jun 26 2014 09:09:27 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Comment: Hello Paul, what do you mean by "in this case"? Is there a valid timezone list?

Comment: The accepted format is discussed here: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14. Certain three-letter zones are supported (as "obsolete zones"), but Date really wants `GMT[+-]HHMM`. Basically, anything supported by [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear how "Internet Message Format" is referred to Javascript ( and I can see another requirement in that spec 'zone = (( "+" / "-" ) 4DIGIT) / obs-zone' ).

Comment: That's the spec used by the Javascript Date class, as mentioned in the `Date.parse()` link above. And That's exactly the same `+/-` followed by 4 digits (`HHMM`) I referred to, just described in a different way. I'm not arguing that this is good or bad, just pointing you to the specs to let you know *why* certain time zones are being rejected.